# Buttons displaced/distorted when hiding the navigation bar (After Rotation)

Tags: ios5, rotation, uinavigationbar, quartz-core

My application has two ViewControllers linked with NavigationController. The First NavigationController has one view with buttons and one view with labels. This view is a circular rotating menu and it represents my home page. The views can rotate with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation - QuartzCore (apparently it's causing the issue) on touchesMoved:.

I wanted to hide the NavigationBar only in this view, so I used *setNavigationBarHidden:YES* on *ViewWillAppear*. Then show the bar on *ViewWillDisappear*.

On the simulator, everything works as expected until i rotate the first ViewController, when i rotate then click on any button (go to the second ViewController) then click on Back (to go back to my first ViewController), everything will be [distorted](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/FGyplq_SAz0rG1eEKlH8CNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink)!.

1. I tried to fix the issue by adding *[self.view setBounds:[[UIScreen
   mainScreen]bounds]];* *[self.view setFrame:[[UIScreen
   mainScreen]bounds]];* in *ViewDidLoad* method or *ViweWillAppear*,
   the issue remains.
2. I tried to set NavigationBar alpha to 0 in *ViewWillAppear* and set
       it to 1 on *ViewWillDisappear* and I tried
       self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES both
       options didn't resolve the problem.
3. I tried to set programmatically views, buttons and labels positions
       in *ViewWillAppear* and it doesn't resolve the problem.
4. I doubted the animation so I removed it but it hasn't any effect on the problem.

As a beginner I'm unable to resolve this issue, please help!

**ViewController.h** (first ViewController)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *aView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *bView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *bimg1;
…
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
…
-(void) rotateTo:(CGFloat)x andY:(CGFloat)y;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize aView = _aView;
…
@synthesize bimg1 = _bimg1;
…
@synthesize label1 = _label1;
…

static inline double toradians (double degrees) {
return degrees * M_PI/180;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    ![enter image description here][1][super viewDidLoad];
    //Set text font
    [_label1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Consolas" size:16]];
…
    [self.view setBounds:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    [self.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    printf("Aview x: %f     | Aview y: %f \n",self.aView.frame.origin.x, self.aView.frame.origin.y);
    printf("Aview width: %f | Aview height: %f \n",self.aView.frame.size.width,    self.aView.frame.size.height);
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint LastTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat LasTouchx = LastTouchPoint.x;
    CGFloat LasTouchy = LastTouchPoint.y;

    CGPoint CenterPoint = self.view.center;
    CGFloat x = LasTouchx - CenterPoint.x;
    [self rotateTo:x andY:y];
}

-(void) rotateTo:(CGFloat)x andY:(CGFloat)y {
    CGFloat angle = x/y;
    angle = atan(angle);
    angle = angle * 360/M_PI;
    angle *= 0.0174532925;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    self.aView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle); 
    self.bView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle); 

    self.bimg1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.bimg2.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.bimg3.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.bimg4.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);

    self.label1.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.label2.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.label3.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    self.label4.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setBimg1:nil];
    … 
    [self setAView:nil];
    [self setBView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
 }
```

Comment: I noticed that while translating from the first ViewController to the second, the first view stretches (apparently the NavigationBar is squeezing the view)! it remains squeezed!… any idea how to avoid this? each time I go to the second ViewController and go back to the first, it squeezes more…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I figured out the problem… The autoresize of the main View was squeezing my subviews when the NavigationController is hidden or not. so i added self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO; to ViewDidLoad and the problem is fixed.

Comment: You have no idea how grateful I am for this answer. This can also be done in interface builder under the Attributes inspector. Just uncheck the "Autoresize Subviews" box.